# Jhipster OIDC config for authorization code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

First, my English is not very well. So I'm sorry if it may make you confused with my question!

I am using jhipster 6.10.3

My application use authorization code flow with Keycloak

I see in jhipster security config

```
http
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
    .and()
        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
    .and()
        .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
    .and()
        .frameOptions()
        .deny()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    .and()
        .oauth2Login()
    .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
            .and()
        .and()
            .oauth2Client();
```

They config authenticationEntryPoint use problemSupport by zalando

When I access a secure API. It return result:

```
{
  "type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Unauthorized",
  "status" : 401,
  "detail" : "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path" : "/api/users",
  "message" : "error.http.401"
}
```

Then if I remove this config: authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)

It will redirect to keycloak login.

**My question is:**

**What should I config for my application?**

1. Config at keycloak two client. One with access type **Public** for Frontend App. One with access type **Confidential** for Backend App. -> My FE Application will redirect to keycloak when unauthorize
2. Config at keycloak one client with access type **Confidential**. And remove this config: authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport). -> My BE Application will redirect to keycloak when unauthorize

**Should I config any request not secure will redirect to keycloak?**

Comment: Option 2, is the closest to what the Oauth working group recommend, if you have a dynamic back-end, then it should initiate the OIDC flow, the front end ideally should not get exposed to the access token, as it's difficult to secure in a public client. The back-end can more securely store the access token, and simply issue the front end with a cookie once the user is authenticated.

Comment: Tks you for your answer, but if I config option 2, then all request will be redirect to keycloak, include /api? So if third party want to integrate with my system, how can they parse response, because all request will be redirect to login page?

Comment: Depends who the 3rd party is, if its another system generally they will use the "client credentials" grant which does not involve the browser so they wont be redirected.
You simply create a client for client credentials grant in keycloak, and provide them with the client id and secret.
They then know that to access your api they first call keycloak with the id and secret to get an access token, then they make the request to your api with the token.
Because it's a direct call via the back channel there is no browser so they wont be redirect to anything.